# How do I make an system, that is using random encounters as compare value to access the right array

Tags: javascript, html, function

I want to make a system that is using the encounter variable (which is generating a random enemy) and make it so, that the function is using the corresponding array for the right encounter. If conditions would work, but in case of adding more enemies, lets say 100, that would be impossible to implement. I'm open for every advice
Thanks in advance!

link for source: [Source code](http://playcode.io/testballon?tabs=console&script.js&output)

```js
// Player variables
var pStats = [100, 15, 20, 3];
var pIds = ["pH", "pD", "pAD", "pI"];


// Enemy variables
var eIds = ["eN", "eH", "eD", "eAD"];
var enemies = ["Zombie", "Assassin", "Werewolf"];
var Zombie = ["Zombie", 50, 10, 10];
var Assassin = ["Assassin", 100, 20, 20];
var Werewolf = ["Werewolf", 100, 30, 10];


// init function
window.onload = function() {
  
  
  // pushes the created stats into DOM
    function statPush(value, id) {
    for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
      addStats(value[i], id[i]);
    }
  }
  
  // creates html element and value
  function addStats(value, id) {
    var elem = document.getElementById(id);
    var text = document.createTextNode(value);
    elem.appendChild(text);
  }
  
  // invoke statPush
  statPush(pStats, pIds);
  
  // random encounter
  var encounter = enemies[Math.floor(Math.random() * 3)];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use an object with all enemies, like

```
var enemies = {
        zombie: {
            eN: "Zombie",
            eH: 50,
            eD: 10,
            eAD: 10
        },
        assassin: {
            eN: "Assassin",
            eH: 100,
            eD: 20,
            eAD: 20
        },
        werewolf: {
            eN: "Werewolf",
            eH: 100,
            eD: 30,
            eAD: 10
        },
        // add more enemies
    };
```

Usage:

```
var enemyNames = Object.keys(enemies),
    randomEnemy = enemyNames[Math.floor(Math.random() * enemyNames.length)];
```

Access to an enemy data:

```
console.log(enemies[randomEnemy].name); // gets the name of the random enemy
```

Comment: Thanks, got a solution!